# Flask API format

Tags: python, api, rest, flask

I am trying to set up a Python API through flask.
Is it better to put parameter in route, for example:
HTTP GET IP_ADDRESS/users/string:user_name

or to put the parameter within the request json, for example:
HTTP GET IP_ADDRESS/users
body: {'user_name':<user_name>}

I usually use the latter option, but the tutorials I have seen on flask all uses the former.

I disagree with the duplicate tag as I do not think it answers my question.

Comment: this will tell you when to pass parameter in request body or request param , choice is your how you goona send, both way are good

Comment: @sahasrara62 No it does not? Where does it tell me when to pass parameter in request body or request param?